# OmniauthCallbacksController#failure - when clicking "Don't Allow" for facebook connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

using rails 3 + devise + omniauth to facebook connect. In the permissions dialog, if the user clicks "don't allow" the user is redirected to:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request." for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Jun 20 16:54:42 -0700 2011
  Processing by Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"error_description"=>"The user denied your request.", "error_reason"=>"user_denied", "error"=>"access_denied"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 2ms
```

How can I gain control and serve a .js file to handle this gracefully. Right now, it is redirecting to the root and showing the site is a small little dialog.

Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Seems you are using omniauthable from devise. In this case, you can see the code for Devise::OmniauthCAllbackController#failure action [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb).

So, you gain the controller you have to create a controller say omniauth_controller as -

```
class OmniauthController < Devise::OmniauthCAllbackController

   def failure
      #handle you logic here..
      #and delegate to super.
      super
   end
end
```

This should work. Also you need to add "devise_for" routes for your omniauth controller.

Comment: Thanks tried the above but it's not taking. What do you mean by "Also you need to add "devise_for" routes for your omniauth controller" ?

Comment: For similar type of problem see this - http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2. Here you should look for how registrations controller is used with it's actions to override, device actions. Also there is path added to routes.rb file as - devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}  
You may check first episode as well, if you need any background for this.

Comment: it's odd I have the exact same problem, I've inherited the callbacks controller and put in my own failure method, and the logs even say `Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML` however none of my code in there is actually execute... still looking into it